# VBScript syntax highlighting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vbscript, visual-studio-2013

How can I tell Visual Studio to use VB-style syntax highlighting?

I'm running a VBScript program. During programming I use Visual Studio for Debugging which works without problems.

However syntax highlighting is wrong. Visual Studio detects the file as JavaScript file and therefore the highlighting is wrong and code hard to read.

This is the current situation:

[image: wrong highlighting]

This is the desired situation:

[image: correct highlighting]

Comment: What is your file extension? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2007/11/30/did-you-know-how-to-get-syntax-highlighting-for-a-given-file-extension.aspx

Comment: Du There is no extension since it is code from debugging a running program. I already tried the setting for extensionless files but it doesn't work since it is no physical file.